# Understanding "(sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0" from va_arg macro

Tags: c, types, binary, sizeof

When looking into code for the va_arg macro (with MSVC), I came across this if else section.

```
((sizeof(t) > sizeof(__int64) || (sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0) ? ... : ...
```

While I understand the meaning of the first part, based on my understanding of binary and sizeof, the second part seems to always be false. Is there a datatype that would satisfy the conditions of this subexpression:

```
(sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0
```

Comment: `x & (x-1)` only equals zero when `x` is a power of `2`

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
(sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0
```

Will be true if `sizeof(t)` is not a power of 2.  While this will be true for most if not all basic types, it could be the case for aggregate types such an array or struct.

If the size is a power of 2, subtracting 1 from that value will result in a value that has no bits in common with the size, so a bitwise AND of those value would be 0.  If the size is not a power of 2, the highest bit set will remain unchanged when subtracting 1, so a bitwise AND of those values will result in a non-zero value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. When I was trying to think it out on paper I only used powers of two, so no wonder I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

2^n = 1000...000

2^n & 2^n -1 = 1000...000 & 0111...111 = 0000...000 = 0

(0 != 0) == false

If the size(t) is a power of 2, (sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != returns false.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).